# What is the Composer.Json file and what is it used for?

Tags: magento2, module, composer, json

I would like to know what the composer.json file is actually used for when I create a new module.

I know it's an optional file that can be created when I create a new module so why include it?

Take the magento/catalog composer.json file as an example, what is it doing?

```
{
    "name": "magento/module-catalog",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
    "php": "~7.0.13|~7.1.0",
    "magento/module-store": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-eav": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-cms": "102.0.*",
    "magento/module-indexer": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-customer": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-theme": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-checkout": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-backend": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-widget": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-wishlist": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-tax": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-msrp": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-catalog-inventory": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-directory": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-catalog-rule": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-product-alert": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-url-rewrite": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-page-cache": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-quote": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-config": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-media-storage": "100.2.*",
    "magento/framework": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-ui": "101.0.*"
   },
   "suggest": {
    "magento/module-cookie": "100.2.*",
    "magento/module-sales": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "Sample Data version:100.2.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
   "version": "102.0.5",
   "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
   ],
   "autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Catalog\\": ""
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer is a PHP dependency manager. Magento uses it to package component (module, metapackage i.e a set modules,theme, language etc). It defines the dependencies needed to run a package. For more information  go to [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/build/composer-integration.html)